# I am confused about how to install package 'pymc' into iPython on Mac

Tags: python, package, ipython, canopy, pymc

I am new to Python and iPython. I have problem installing the package 'pymc' into iPython on Mac.

I basically followed these [instructions](http://www.pa.uky.edu/~robert/html/epd_+_pymc_on_newton.html).

Here is what I did:

First, I downloaded the pymc source file from github, and then I unzipped this under the folder "Document", this unzipped folder was called "pymc-devs-pymc-79bc2dc";

Second, from a terminal, I typed:

```
cd /Users/shijiabian/Documents/pymc-devs-pymc-79bc2dc
```

Third, I wanted to make canopy python to be my default python. Under the directory of "pymc-devs-pymc-79bc2dc", I typed:

```
export PATH=/Users/shijiabian/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:$PATH
```

This step followed https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-. But I was not sure if I need type this under different directory. However, the output looked correct for me.

Fourth step, I tried two different approaches.

The first approach: I typed the codes below into terminal:

```
cd pymc-devs-pymc-b6aa943/
python setup.py config_fc --fcompiler gfortran build
python setup.py install
```

However, there were errors returned after entering python setup.py config_fc --fcompiler gfortran build. I was wondering if I needed install other packages.

The second approach was that I used pip directly:

```
pip install
```

The installation was successful. Then I moved to the next step.

Fifth step, I still followed the instruction

```
> ipython
>>> In [1]: import pymc
```

There was a warning message:

> Warning: statsmodels and/or patsy not found, not importing glm submodule.

I was quite confused if I did anything improper.

Answer (score 1):

pip install  should be your first idea when attempting to install new python packages

Here you did nothing improper, the warning is raised cause module statsmodels and patsy are missing, but you know what to do now ;-)

Comment: Yes. I also found that I did not do anything wrong. I realized that I need use this package in the iPython instead of in the terminal. Thanks.